# POST request ajax jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run post request to parse json format data into the page. An example query is:

```
    $("#click").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://ut-pc-236:9000/kanye/flow/search",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                data: {
                        "fromDate":"2011-01-01",
                        "toDate":"2011-03-16T14:35:00Z",
                        "limitTotalFlows":1000,
                        "operator":"AND",
                        "keyValues":[ "J0419:E", "J0410:AMPY", "J1043:BEDFORD" ]
                        },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

but it gives an error - bad request (400). I guess it should be some syntax error since the get method works ok. If anyone can help I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: The obvious problem with the request is that you are claiming you are sending JSON while not sending JSON… but that's speculation as we don't know what the server side code is doing to determine if the request is "good".

Comment: the server side is returning json format data

Comment: The server side is returning a `400 Bad Request`. I'm talking about what the client is sending.

Comment: Is it a cross-domain request?

Comment: yes, it is. But everything is configured since the GET method already works

Comment: Maybe the server is accepting only Get requests to the specified URL; POST requests may be blocked. My explanation is based on your notice that Get requests works fine.

Comment: It should work. I tried running the post method with cURL and the request is successful. It must be the jquery part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending a valid json object as you claim to be doing with the `contentType`.

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your data:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 
    "fromDate":"2011-01-01",
    "toDate":"2011-03-16T14:35:00Z",
    "limitTotalFlows":1000,
    "operator":"AND",
    "keyValues":[ "J0419:E", "J0410:AMPY", "J1043:BEDFORD" ]
}),
```

Comment: In addition to stringify try setting dataType: "json" too

Comment: @Ragnar — That overrides the content-type of the response. It should be avoided in having the response send the correct content type. It certainly won't help when the response is Bad Request.

Comment: According to the jQuery documentation, the data may be a plain object or a string. Also, the behavior of the AJAX method may be modified.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/